# Printing the PreparedStatement in postgreSQL driver

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, postgresql-9.1, c3p0

I need a way to see the query being sent to PostgreSQL from my Java program. I am using `c3p0` JDBC connectionpool for getting the connection. When I use `toString` method on the PreparedStatement, it gives me

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement@577b57a3
```

My code:

```
public void readData1() {
    Connection con = null;
    try
    {
        con = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        java.sql.Timestamp ts= new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        String query= "INSERT INTO TEST_DATA values(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setDate(1,new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        stmt.setInt(2, 100);
        stmt.setTimestamp(3,ts );
        System.out.println(stmt.toString());
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
        stmt.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not read from DB, error: "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try { con.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

}
```

Could someone help me how to get sql query from the PreparedStatement?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a prerelease version of c3p0-0.9.5, you might try...

```
System.out.println(stmt.unwrap(PreparedStatement.class).toString());
```

Probably you are not, so you might try this...

```
printInnerStatement( (C3P0ProxyStatement) stmt );
```

with...

```
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.*;

static void printInnerStatement( C3P0ProxyStatement stmt )
{
   java.lang.reflect.Method m = java.io.PrintStream.class.getMethod("println", new Class[]{Object.class});
   stmt.rawStatementOperation(m, System.out, new Object[]{ C3P0ProxyStatement.RAW_STATEMENT });
}
```

To understand what's going on here (and fix the mistakes I've inevitably made), see [Raw Connection and Statement Operations](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#raw_connection_ops).

Comment: Is there a way that I can get the sql query in a String?